# Detect if all three drop down menu has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three drop down menu's:

```
<div class = "form=group">
<select class = "selecter" id = "day"><option>1<option><option>2</option></select>
<select class = "selecter" id = "month"><option>1<option><option>2</option></select>
<select class = "selecter" id = "year"><option>1<option><option>2</option></select>
</div>
```

I want to detect if all three fields have been selected so I can validate the date. I tried the following:

```
$('.selecter').on('change', function() {
console.log("Something is changed!");
});
```

But it fires up on each drop down. How can I add each function to it so I can detect after all selecter class has been changed? Also I can click on next drop down after one is selected? thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class or add something else to the selects that is easy to check on change, and compare the number of changed selects to the number of selects to know if all of them have been changed :

```
var selects = $('.selecter').length;

$('.selecter').on('change', function() {
    $(this).addClass('changed');

    if ( $('.changed').length == selects ) {
        // someone changed all three selects ?
    }
});
```

Comment: Just what I wanted, Thank You!